# Defining a variable as a range - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I think I'm losing my mind - how do you declare a variable as a string and then set it equal to a range in an Excel workbook in VB.NET?  In VBA this was easy:

```
Dim SQL as string
SQL = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("SQL")
```

If I try do something like this in VB.NET (in Visual Studio 2015), first I can't find Activeworkbook.  Second, if I try `Excel.Range("SQL")`, I get an error saying that `'Range' is an interface type and cannot be used as an expression`.  Also, it doesn't look like the `Range` data type exists either.  Surely this functionality exists in VB.NET, right?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work on Excel since VB.NET, first you must add the reference to your Project :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

To Add a Reference :

In `Solution Explorer`, right-click on the `References` node and choose `Add Reference`.

Import the Reference in your code :

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Try to use this code :

```
Dim AppExcel As New Excel.Application 'Create a new Excel Application
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = AppExcel.Workbooks.Add() 'Create a new workbook
Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet = workbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Create variable a Sheet, Sheet1 must be in WorkBook

'Work with range
Dim cellRange1 As Excel.Range = sheet.Range("A1") 'Range with text address
cellRange1.Value = "Text in Cell A1"

Dim cellRange2 As Excel.Range = sheet.Cells(2, 2) 'Range("B2:B2") with index; Cells(N°Row,N°Col) 
cellRange2.Value = "Text in Cell B2"


Dim tableRange3 As Excel.Range = sheet.Range("A1:F4") 'Range with text address

Dim tableRange4 As Excel.Range = sheet.Range(sheet.Cells(1, 1), sheet.Cells(4, 6)) 'Range("A1:F4") with index; Cells(N°Row,N°Col) 

AppExcel.Visible = True 'To display the workbook
```

Code without variable sheet

```
Dim AppExcel as New Excel.Application
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = AppExcel.Workbooks.Add()
'Range
Dim cellrange1 as Excel.Range = AppExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I already have that reference, I think.  It's displayed as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  Is that the correct one?  I thought the Imports statement was only needed if I didn't want to write out all the object qualifiers.  It's not necessary, is it?

You're example above worked, but why can't I do this:

Dim AppExcel as New Excel.Application
Dim cellrange1 as Excel.Range = AppExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("SQL").Value.

I don't like to nest variables in other variables, but what I wrote above doesn't seem to work in Visual Studio.

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly You can't do this because, you must create a WorkBook objet and you can not assign an object type to a Range type. 2nd Why put SQL in Range ( "SQL"), which represents SQL; must be an address Range.

Comment: Why can't I assign an object type to a Range variable?  How would I assign a range's value/text then?  I'm new to VB.NET, but I'm sure you can reference a named range, correct?  If cell A1 is named "BudgetSQL", it should be fine to put "BudgetSQL" in the Cell1 parameter for the Range object, right?

Comment: you can not assign a Range value type to a Range type : Excel.Range = AppExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("SQL").Value; For the range name, Yes, you're right, you can reference a named range.

Comment: It took a little while, but I think a combination of Scott's answer below and your answer helped me understand why I can't assign the Value object to Range variable.  Sorry if I'm being slow - I'm trying to switch from VBA to VB.NET.  I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to start from your application object. Suppose that's `AppExcel`:

```
Dim AppExcel As New Excel.Application
```

From there, you could do:

```
Dim cellrange1 as Excel.Range = AppExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Range("SQL")
```

Because you've declared `cellrange1` as a `Range` it can't be set to  `Range("SQL").Value`.
`Value` returns an `object` which is the value contained in that `Range`.

That's so wordy. To put it (maybe) more clearly, `Range("SQL")` returns a `Range`. `Range("SQL").Value` returns an object.

If you want to get the value, that would be `cellrange1.Value`, or perhaps `cellrange1.Text`. Assuming that the range contains some sort of SQL, I'd go with `Text`.

An unfortunate aspect of Excel interop programming is that many properties return objects rather than strongly-typed values. For example, the object returned by `Range.Text` is always going to be a `string`, but the property still returns an `object`. That means that Visual Studio intellisense will often not tell you what type a property returns. You'll need to look up properties and functions in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.aspx) to really know what they return.

Comment: So, Visual Studio doesn't throw an error when I write the line above, but Intellisense doesn't show the Range object in the dropdown list after I type Sheets("MySheet").  Do you know why that is?  And that makes some sense when you were explaining the Text vs. Value properties.  Do you happen to know why I could set a string variable in VBA to a Range object?  I looked up the Value objects in VBA vs. interop and they look very similar but interop has "As Object" as the data type, while VBA doesn't show a data type in the Object Browser.  Is this the difference you are referring to?

Comment: `Sheets()` probably returns an `object`. It forces you to just somehow know what the actual type is. That's one of the problems with Excel interop. A function or property should return a meaningful type (at least in a strongly-typed language like C#.)